# Basic interpolation, up- and down- scaling

Tags: c++, algorithm, image, interpolation

I have 2-dmensional array, it's an interpretation of a monochrome image. I'd like to resize it to specific, known size. The quality is not essential. 
If I need to resize it to 2x or 4x size, it's okay, just using the nearest neighbor interpolation, placing 4 pixels instead of one for example.
Basically, if I need to interpolate my image to x1.5, I'll increase the size x3 and decrease it x2. Am I right?
But what should I do, when I need to enlarge my image to 3x size, for example?
How should be pixels placed then, in an interpolated array?
It would be great if you give any info, codes, links to other sites.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trick is thinking the opposite way: Don't try to place a pixel of the source image into the scaled image, but find a pixel in the source image that should be placed into the scaled image.

It would look something like that:

```
float scaleFactor = 3.0f;

for (int y=0; y < scaledImageHeight; y++)
  for (int x=0; x < scaledImageWidth; x++) {
    int sourceImageX = (int)std::max(x * 1.0f / scaleFactor, (float)(sourceImageWidth - 1));
    int sourceImageY = (int)std::max(y * 1.0f / scaleFactor, (float)(sourceImageHeight - 1));
    scaledImage[y * scaledImageWidth + x] = sourceImage[sourceImageY * sourceImageWidth + sourceImageX];
  }
```

For demonstration purposes this code clamps the image on the lower right, so the program doesn't crash because of an array overrun (that's what the std::max is for).

Comment: Wow, thanks very much, now I'll try to understand this piece of code. Hope everything will be okay.